# Drupal: How do I populate an email field from a single user “Name” reference?

Tags: drupal, entityreference

How do I populate an email field from a single user “Name” reference?

I have a content type in which I use an entity reference to reference a Name field in a user account. I am trying to populate an email field in the content type with the email of the entity referenced above. I have tried creating an entity reference view and can get it to show and save: Name, Email Address in the node. However, because of some rules I am using, I really need them to be saved to separate fields. So I tried the Entity Reference Autofill module which seems like it does exactly what I am looking for, but, it only works with existing fields, and for some reason, I can’t get the user account fields to show-up as existing fields when trying to add them to the content type.

So, is there a way for a single reference to populate more fields using the initial reference as a ‘key’?

Or…

Is there a way to get user account fields to show-up as existing fileds so I can just use the Entity Reference Autofill module?

Thanks so much.

Comment: If nobody answers try to ask in http://drupal.stackexchange.com/.